# Issue with value returned by python function

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I am trying to do a simple multiprocessing example. In which i am trying to run a simple shell script in multiprocessing thread pool. Script is getting executed but the output of the script is not returned properly to the calling function.

```
 def call_proc(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print "Out" +out
    print "Error" +err
    return (out, err)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    results = []
    for i in range(1,5):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(call_proc ("./test.sh")))

    # Close the pool and wait for each running task to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print results
    for result in results:
        out, err = result.get()
        print("out: {} err: {}".format(out, err))
```

I am getting the following output along with an exception when i run the python script

> Output :Test Done
>
> Error  :
>
> Output :Test Done
>
> Error  :
>
> Output :Test Done
>
> Error  :
>
> Output :Test Done
>
> Error  :
>
> Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "osshm_multiprocess.py", line 25, in
>   
>       out, err = result.get()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
>       raise self._value TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Not sure where it was going wrong.

Comment: you forgot comma between `call_proc` and  `("./test.sh")` - now you execute `call_proc("./test.sh")` and its result is used a `apply_async` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me you forgot comma `,` between `call_proc` and `("./test.sh")`

Now you execute `call_proc("./test.sh")` and its result is used a `apply_async` argument

You do something like this

```
function_result = call_proc("./test.sh")
pool.apply_async(function_result)
```

But you have to do

```
function_name = call_proc
function_args = ("./test.sh", ) # tuple with arguments
pool.apply_async(function_name, function_args) # <-- comma between name and args
```

so you need

```
pool.apply_async(call_proc, ("./test.sh",))
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that you are already obtaining a tuple from

```
out, err = result.get()
```

remove call to `get()`